# Social Media Embed Problems With the URL Embed module

Tags: 8

we have been using the alpha version of url_embed with Drupal core 8.9.1. Locally, I am now testing the beta version.  This update also involved updating the Embed module from 1.0 to 1.4.

On the alpha version of url_embed, I could get the LinkedIn embed to work, but not Twitter or Instagram. On beta, Twitter and Instagram embeds work, but not LinkedIn. We are using Ckeditor for these embeds.

Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong? Any help is more than welcome.  I'm reading the code of both url_embed and embed to get some clues, but so far no luck.

Comment: I'm not familiar with [url_embed](https://www.drupal.org/project/url_embed), but the project page says it works out of the box with Twitter and Instagram, but doesn't mention LinkedIn.

Comment: Interesting point.  But it was working with LinkedIn in the alpha version.  I'm also trying to get it to work with Facebook, but no luck.